# Totally independent forms in tabcontrol

Tags: vb.net, forms, tabcontrol

I'm designing an application on VB.net and I'm newbie as well. 
I thought about the general architecture of the application and came up with the following idea.

- the application is made of different modules
- the user can run different modules in the same time
- each module will run his main form in a different tab in tabcontrol
- each module has his own modal forms, mode-less windows, messages, ... etc.

Before going through much development details, I started first with trying this design. Though, I couldn't first embed dynamically a form in tab during run time and even after some workarounds, I couldn't make the modules run perfectly in parallel. For example when I have a modal window displayed in a module, the whole application freezes while I expect only the related tab to freeze and be able to switch to the others to do some work.

Does anyone know how to make the tab contents completely separate and not have one freezes the other?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to have separate modules/forms to run more than one task simultaneously. The issue you are having with the UI freezing is you are running all operations on the primary thread. You need to multithread the application. Do a quick search on stackoverflow for multithreading vb.net. If you can't find anything let me know and I'll do the search and provide links.